# Visual Studio "Extensions and Updates" remains disabled

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

Recently, I disabled all the extensions at "Extensions and Updates" window in Visual Studio 2017. Now I am trying to enable them but it doesn't work. When I enabled the extensions Visual Studio says:

```
These changes will take effect the next time Microsoft Visual Studio is opened.
```

But, when I close the VS and reopen it again, they remain disabled. I tried to restart the system after closing the VS, but this also didn't work.

Is there any one knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: I haven't had this problem specifically, but have had other problems with Visual Studio 2017 where certain features cease to work correctly.  NOTE: this will cause Visual Studio to do essentially a "factory reset". In Windows Explorer, browse to "`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio". There should be a "15.0" folder, as well as several odd ones like "15.0xxx". Keep the "15.0" folder, but delete (or rename or move if you want to be cautious) the other "15.0xxx" folders. Note that this will reset ALL of your custom settings including your login credentials for VS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any one knows how to solve this issue?

Since there is no specific error info, to resolve this issue, I would like provide you some troubleshootings:

- **Make sure you are using latest version of Visual Studio**.

  I test it with the latest version 15.5.2 without this issue. If you are not in the latest version, please update your Visual Studio to latest version first.
- **Run Visual Studio in safe mode**:

  Please open an administrative CMD window and navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE` and run these commands:

  `devenv /safemode`

  It prevents all third-party VSPackages from loading when Visual Studio starts, thus ensuring stable execution. if it works, this issue should be caused by the extensions and you need to remove the installed extensions under Tools—Extensions and Updates.
- **Clean the extension cache**:

  If it doesn’t work in safe mode, please have a try with delete or rename the following folders:
  C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0
  C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0

  Meanwhile, run visual studio as **administrator**, disable any Anti-Virus or Anti-Spyware software on your computer and clean %temp% folder.

Hope this helps.